# Set app switcher icon for add-to-homescreen Chrome webapp?

Tags: android, google-chrome, homescreen

I've got the manifest file set up, icons in place, etc.

I can see the correct icon on my homescreen:
[image: I can see the correct icon on my homescreen.]

The typical web favicon shows up just fine:
[image: The typical web favicon shows up just fine.]

But when I go to the app switcher, I see the Chrome icon:
[image: But when I go to the app switcher, I see the Chrome icon.]

Is it possible to customize that icon? The docs state that the text isn't changeable but they don't say anything about the image.

Comment: Removing the `google-chrome-app` tag: this is not a Chrome App in [this sense](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps) (or rather, [this sense](https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/mobile-chrome-apps)).

Comment: Yeah, I realize it's more of a glorified bookmark than anything else, but Chrome respects favicons for bookmarks, so I figured it may be possible...

Answer (score 1):

The image is pulled from the manifest when it is added to the homescreen and also from the page when it is loaded.  There was a bug in Chrome a while ago where an Added to Homescreen experience when launched would only display "Chrome Beta" or "Chrome".  This should be fixed now.